# How to convert SDK jar files to .Net dll files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms

I am developing mobile app using xamarin forms, the application works on POS device with a specific .jar files comes with device, how can i use these **jar** files as **dll** in my project? Please help

[This is the URL of the Device Company](https://www.wiseasy.com/page/wangpos.htm)

Comment: You don't.  A jar cannot be converted to a .Net DLL.  It would have to be rewritten in .Net.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: @Jason I tried this, but it doesn't work and i tried IKVMC tool either, is there any other way ?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: @Jason please find the below description  of my problem

Answer (score 0):

sorry for poor description of my problem,
OK , I tried to Add the JarBinding Project and i changed the Build Action to Embedded Jar and then i added this project as Reference in the Portable xamarin forms Project , finally when i tried to use it in the project i can't reach all classes 
but the same Jar or Package have more than that like BankCard and Core as Image [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRKUo.png) shows with Java Language.

[Creating the jarBinding Project and add the Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNif5.png)

[add JarBinding Project as Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OOwP.png)

[here i can not reach all Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPahl.png)

[the Classes in Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRKUo.png)